# What is the proper formula in getting the total scorecard?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have this certain part of my exercise I just can't finish solving:

Data:
Kpi1 15
Kpi2 25
Kpi3 10
Kpi4 44

Question. What is the total score?

Kpi1 goal-  <=20
     Weight- 10%
Kpi2 goal-  >=20
     Weight- 50%
Kpi3 goal- >=20
     Weight- 20%
Kpi4 goal- >=40
     Weight- 20%

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scores by KPI are in B1:B4, maybe:

```
=(B1<=20)*0.1+(B2>=20)*0.5+(B3>=20)*0.2+(B4>=40)*0.2
```